# Where do I submit XML reports after WACK has finished?

Tags: wpf, desktop-application, app-certification-kit

We have WPF desktop application which we have packed in setup executable. Because of SmartScreen we need to certificate our application. We have used Windows App Certification Kit (WACK) from Windows 10 SDK to generate XML reports. And now we have to submit those reports to Microsoft.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/win_cert/windows-certification-portal

We have created developer account as company, and when I click on submitting reports:

```
Test locally and upload the results     
After your run the Windows App Certification Kit tests, upload the results to the Windows Certification Dashboard.
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/dashboard/

It directs me to Windows Hardware Dev Center dashboard?!?

Were do we upload our WACK reports for our desktop application certification?

Comment: Did you resolve this? We also have no idea where to submit the results.

Comment: No, only way is to buy an instant SmartScreen reputation EV code certificate (like here https://www.ksoftware.net/code-signing-certificates/ ). Or to have enough users to allow your setup to proceed. There is no mention how much is enough (user number).

Comment: Ah we bought one already. I assumed this process gave you even more benefits.

Comment: @rolls I was disappointed too.

Comment: Bit of a waste of time. They should discontinue the tool.

Comment: There should be an upload button however I have heard it is not present from some users.

Comment: There is a button but it just take you to a 404 page.

Answer (score 0):

I have opened a ticket with Microsoft regarding this and it turns out the "classic desktop" logo program has been discontinued.

The only way you can "certify" your application is either the [Ready for Windows program](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/ready-for-windows/) or the [Windows Desktop Application program](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/appxpkg/windows-desktop-application-program).